# jQuery animated scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have problem with animate scroll in jQuery.

I have a script for animated scroll but animation doesn't works for me.

Here is code:

```
$(document).ready(function{
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {
        var target = $(this.href);
        if( target.length ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: target.offset().top
            }, 1000);
        }
    });            
})
```

Does anybody know what I can do?

Answer (score 0):

The logic is correct. However, I believe the implementation might have some issues. You basically want to scroll to an element with `id` equal to `href` of `a`. In the following example, a div is defined with `id = "div"` and an anchor tag with `href="#div"`. Also, `$(this.href)` would give you the entire url, so you have get the target using `$(this).attr("href");`

```
<div id="div">Scroll Here</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <a href="#div">Click</a>

   $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) { 
        var target = $(this).attr("href"); // gets the id of the div via href attribute
        if(target.length) {
          $('html,body').animate({
           scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
           }, 800);
        }
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yz6cunjs/1/

Comment: But in your example animate doesn't have effect to :( I know how this code works and i implement it correct, i just have problem with animating it, it scrolls without animate. :(

Comment: It does. If you scroll all the way down to and 'Click', it would scroll to the div. You might have to change the duration from 1000 to 4000 or more.

Comment: In my browser it doesn't (firefox)

Comment: fixed the link. Try http://jsfiddle.net/yz6cunjs/1/. I found out that this.href was giving you the entire url instead of the value of href attribute. It has to be $(this).attr("href");

Answer (score 0):

So if you want animated Scrolling try the code below. Set a class you want the animated scrolling to go to. In this case I just have that bottom div with a class of .bottom and that button will send you to whatever class its set to in the function. Im sure you can implement this anyway you want it to work.

I hope this helps,

```js
function scrollToBottom(){
  var lastElementTop = $('.bottom').position().top;
  var scrollAmount = lastElementTop + 75;

  $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: scrollAmount}, 900);
};
```

```css
div{
  height: 650px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #2A2B2C;
  }

.bottom{
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color:#7C85FF;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<h2>Hello, click the button!</h2>
<button onclick="scrollToBottom()">Click me fool!</button>

<div></div>

<div class="bottom">
  This is the bottom
</div>
```

Answer (score -4):

What is the if( target.length ) { meant to do, you already know the element exists, and the href also exists, as in the jquery selector you have it required that the first character of the href is a #.

This should work:
I changed your .length line to be > 1 so only if it's got something after the # in the href.

```
$(document).ready(function{
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {
        var target = $(this.href);
            if( target.length > 1 ) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It checks if that element exists, it's a fairly well known method of checking if something in the DOM exists

Comment: @Matthew Cowley - look up "Javascript Truthiness" (since my first comment wasn't helpful at all)

Comment: Yup, it check is that exists.

Comment: Edited, to explain what I meant. And has code that seems to work for me.

Comment: Hi - you've been downvoted because you have attempted to clarify the question rather than provide an answer to it.  This should be a comment rather than an answer.  In addition, in many languages (including javascript) `if (1)` is the same as `if (1!=0)` so `if (target.length)` is the same as `if (target.length!=0)` which is valid.

Comment: @freedomn-m, I did provide an answer >.<

Comment: Also, why have a check when the original jquery selector must have href with a #

Comment: "What is the if( target.length ) { meant to do?" - looks like a question to me...  I didn't downvote, explaining why others *are*.    Either way, your *edit* should be `if(target.length>0)` which, in javascript, is the same as `if(target.length)`

Comment: @freedomn-m my edit checked wheter something was after the #, as the selector only selects things that have a # at the start of the href....

Comment: I've corrected it now, I'm tired...
My point still stands though, why confirm the href exists when you already know it does.

Comment: Makes more sense like that... as in "what's the point of" - better luck next time :)